# Перевыпуск сертификатов для Telegram бота

Tags: c#, .net, windows, telegram-bot

Для использования [вебхуков](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks) в **Telegram Bot API** (получение уведомлений о событиях) необходимо навесить сертификат безопасности на выбранный порт. Я решил автоматизировать эту операцию и самоподписанный сертификат генерируется и добавляется в хранилище автоматически. Но у сертификата есть дата истечения срока действия. Соответственно в один прекрасный день бот перестанет получать обновления от Telegram. Вопрос как бы вы отслеживали этот момент и на какой срок генерировали бы сертификат безопасности?

Comment: 1) какая операционная система 2) что за сертификат, кто выпустил его

Comment: 1) Windows, в тегах это указано
2) Сертификат самоподписанный, об этом в вопросе тоже написано. Сертификат необходим для создания защищённого SSL/TLS соединения.

Comment: Так самоподписанный вы можете хоть на 10 лет выпустить. А так, планировщик задач-проверка даты-перевыпуск, если истекает

Comment: _"Так самоподписанный вы можете хоть на 10 лет выпустить."_ - Я понимаю. Возможно существуют какие то рекомендации по этому поводу. То есть лучше всего создать задачу в планировщике?

Comment: Ну а как иначе? Я на серверах cron использую для таких дел, это планировщик под linux. Но у меня настоящие сертификаты.

Comment: Для автоматизации SSL сертификатов уже давно был придуман спец. протокол, который зовется `ACME` (Automatic Certificate Management Environment), например бесплатный `Let’s Encrypt` работает по нему выдавая автоматически сертификат по запросу вроде на месяц. Что касается вашей автоматизации с самоподписанными сертификатам то, как по мне это костыль, ибо в этой цепочке нет центра сертификации, который подтвердил бы надежность сертификата, а когда вы сами себе делаете сертификат, ну я хз, это как нарисовать самому себе паспорт и ходить с ним, друзья примут, а остальные?)

Comment: _"друзья примут, а остальные?"_ - Так это нужно лишь для создания защищённого соединения. Зачем получать заверенный сертификат для того чтобы просто создать бота в мессенджере?) Другое дело сайт.

Comment: _"как по мне это костыль"_ - Мне кажется Telegram не стал бы писать об этом в документации, если бы это был костыль.

Comment: _"Для автоматизации SSL сертификатов уже давно был придуман спец. протокол, который зовется ACME (Automatic Certificate Management Environment), например бесплатный Let’s Encrypt работает по нему выдавая автоматически сертификат по запросу вроде на месяц."_ - Каким образом происходит автоматизация?

Comment: Не забывайте пинговать через `@` человека. `Другое дело сайт.` - а чем **веб**хук отличается от сайта? Вы делаете ссылку (сайта), отдаете ее телеграмму, а он туда отправляет POST? запрос. Захотите потом дать этот API другому приложению, а может сделаете еще один API, а у вас там "поддельный" паспорт, что, будете всем клиентам кидать сертификат свой? Я не сказал, что это ненадежно, я сказал, что это костыль, с которым далеко не уехать. `Каким образом происходит автоматизация?` - я думаю вы в состоянии самостоятельно загуглить этот момент?) Я вам лишь дал направление, не более.